# Fazer consulta mysql com INNER JOIN entre servidores diferentes mysql

Tags: mysql

Como poderia efetuar uma consulta com `INNER JOIN` entre servidores diferentes, como exemplificado abaixo:

```
SELECT
    serverA.clinte AS CLIENTE,
     serverB.enderecoCliente AS ENDERECO
FROM
    127.0.0.1.dbo.cliente AS serverA 
    INNER JOIN 192.168.0.1.dbo.clientes AS serverB 
    ON serverA.cli_id = serverB.cli_id
```

Comment: veja a documentação. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-description.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Você precisa especificar o *caminho completo* da tabela; estando ela em outro servidor, deverá especificar não só o *server* mas também *banco* e *esquema*:

> `[server].[database].[schema].[table]`

Ficando algo tipo assim:

```
SELECT
    tabelaServerA.clinte AS CLIENTE,
    tabelaServerB.enderecoCliente AS ENDERECO
FROM
    [127.0.0.1].dbo.schemaDaTabelaCliente.cliente AS tabelaServerA 
INNER JOIN 
    [192.168.0.1].dbo.schemaDaTabelaClientes.clientes AS tabelaServerB 
ON 
    tabelaServerA.cli_id = tabelaServerB.cli_id
```

Comment: Show, obrigado.

Comment: Show de bola. Perfeito.