# Como Realizar Select em Tabelas que estão em Bases de Dados Diferentes SQL SERVER 2008 e 2012

Tags: sql, linked-server

Atualmente Tenho 1 Banco de Dados no SQL SERVER 2008R2 e outro SQL SERVER 2012.

TENHO UMA APLICAÇÃO QUE USA A BASE NO 2008R2 E PRECISO CONSULTAR DADOS QUE ESTAO NO 2012. QUAL O MELHOR CAMINHO?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Fazer consulta mysql com INNER JOIN entre servidores diferentes mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274573/fazer-consulta-mysql-com-inner-join-entre-servidores-diferentes-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim como na [resposta em MySql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274573/fazer-consulta-mysql-com-inner-join-entre-servidores-diferentes-mysql) que o rLinhares citou no comentário, basta especificar o caminho completo da tabela:

> [server].[database].[schema].[table]

Exemplo:

```sql
select *
from tabelaBancoAtual t1
inner join banco2.dbo.tabelaOutroBanco t2
on t1.idFk = t2.id
```